# string matching in javascript / regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the best way to match two strings that contain the same phrase? For example is there a good way to match the following two strings:

```
st1 = 'jenissplendidicecreams'
st2 = 'jenisicecream'
```

What would be the proper regex to match those two strings?

Comment: what are you trying to match? are you trying to check if a specific string is in both of those? (e.g. checking to see if both string contain "jenis"?

Comment: yes. but without using .substring or .slice - is there a regex alternative?

Comment: Should this have any limit? this could take very long for long strings...

Comment: Or are you trying to check that the two strings are the same with the exception that the first contains `splendid` in the middle, and an extra `s` at the end?

Comment: If your specification is that you want to match phrases **in initial position**, please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a regexp which looks like this:

```
/.*j.*e.*n.*i.*s.*i.*c.*e.*c.*r.*e.*a.*m.*/
```

This regexp matches if the string being tested includes all the original characters, in order, but with any arbitrary additional characters in between.

We can build that easily enough by doing

```
function make_regexp(str) {
    var letters = str.split('');
    letters.push(''), letters.unshift('');
    return new RegExp(letters.join('.*'));
}

> make_regexp('jenisicecream')
< /.*j.*e.*n.*i.*s.*i.*c.*e.*c.*r.*e.*a.*m.*/
```

Now test if the second string matches:

```
> make_regexp('jenisicecream').test('jenissplendidicecreams')
< true
```

Comment: But this supports things like: `make_regexp('jenisicecream').test('ajaeanaiasasapalaeanadaiadaiacaeacaraeaaamas') -> true`

Comment: Yes, it does. But that example satisfies the OP's definition of "two strings that contain the same phrase", unless he wants to clarify his definition, to include conditions such as "...the same phrase with a minimum length of x", or "...the same phrases up to a maximum of y".

Comment: Oh okay, nice answer :) *got a +1 from me*

Comment: this answer satisfies my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure but I think you might be looking for something like this?

```js
var str1 = "I have some words!";
var str2 = "I have some very similar words!";

var min = 5;
var max = 6;

var len = str1.length;

for(var i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
  for(var j = min; j<max; j++) 
  {
    var re = new RegExp(str1.substring(i,j));
    console.log(re);

    //Do something when this returns true??
    console.log(re.test(str2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.

You can just use string methods:

```
var name = st1.slice(0, st1.indexOf("splendidicecream"));

return name == st2.slice(0, st2.indexOf("icecream"));
```

Or if you really wanted to use regex:

```
var nameRe = /.+?(?=splendidicecream)/,
    name = st1.match(nameRe)[0];

return st2.startsWith(name);
```

Or harder regex:

```
var nameRe = /.+?(?=splendidicecream)/,
    startsWithNameRe = new RegExp("^" + st1.match(nameRe)[0]);

return startsWithNameRe.test(st2);
```

Comment: what if the re value has to be dynamic? For example can i use a substring to create the re value? For example can i do - st1.slice(0, 5) to generate the re value?

Comment: Is the problem that you are trying to solve that you want to check that both start with the same string? are you guaranteed that the string is that specific length?

Comment: yes, exactly. but no i am not guaranteed that they are a specific length.

Comment: okay, so you want to check if the two strings start with the same characters? up until when, when you hit "splendid" or "icecream"?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that computers have no idea where the words are. Either you could index a whole dictionary or use something that uses a specified distance to get values **(if `string` is str2 and `str` is str1)**:

```
var distance = 8, // Best for your current case
    end      = new RegExp('.{'+distance+'}$', '').exec(string)[0],
    start    = new RegExp('^(.*)'+end+'$', '').exec(string)[1];

function matches (s) {
    return new RegExp('^(?:'+start+').*(?:'+end+')$').test(s);
}

matches(str);
```

---

## Or you can have to computer guess:

```
var min = 1, // Adjust depending on acceptance level
    split = string.split('').reverse().map(function (a,i) {
        if ( (i+1) % min === 0) {
            return a + '.*';
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    }).reverse().join(''),
    regex = new RegExp(split, '');

regex.test('jenissplendidicecreams');
```